# AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'nested_row_splits'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to copy the "Neural machine translation with a Transformer and `Keras`" model from the `tensorflow` website and I have copied everything exactly how they have it. When I go and try to train the model using the data they supplied I keep getting the following Error:

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'nested_row_splits'

the transformer.fit() takes train_batches as the input. 

train_batches is type PrefetchDataset Size 810 and value
<PrefetchDataset element_spec((TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int64, name=None), Tensor<...>
          dtype=tf.int64, name=None)), RaggedTensorSpec(TensorShape([None, None])
```

The error is coming from `tf__masked_loss(label, pred)` in `tensorflow`

Does anyone know what this error means and how to fix it?

I tried to look at the code in `tensorflow` but I can't figure it out. I am literally copy the code from the `tensorflow` website so I have no idea what to do. I can change the data type but I feel like I shouldn't have to do this.

Comment: Please share TF and Python versions you are using.

Comment: I am using python 3.7.16 and tensorflow version 2.10.1

Answer (score 1):

your decoder input must have the same length as the ground truth
i recommend you check the `decoder_input` shape and the `ground_truth` shape
if there are any problems you can normalize that batch length using `decoder_input.to_tensor( )` and `ground_truth.to_tensor( )`

since you mentioned that you are using original [tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/transformer), i recommend you check what you have written in this function :

```
MAX_TOKENS=128
def prepare_batch(pt, en):
    pt = tokenizers.pt.tokenize(pt)      # Output is ragged.
    pt = pt[:, :MAX_TOKENS]    # Trim to MAX_TOKENS.
    pt = pt.to_tensor()  # Convert to 0-padded dense Tensor

    en = tokenizers.en.tokenize(en)
    en = en[:, :(MAX_TOKENS+1)]
    en_inputs = en[:, :-1].to_tensor()  # Drop the [END] tokens
    en_labels = en[:, 1:].to_tensor()   # Drop the [START] tokens

    return (pt, en_inputs), en_labels
```